# Getting the list of installed applications excluding built-in ones

Tags: android

I want to get the list of installed applications. But need to exclude the default built in applications. like bluetooth, App vault.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `built in applications` and `applications whose icon does not display on UI` is totally different

Comment: Yeah, @VladyslavMatviienko is totally right......these two are totally different. Could you tell us which one is your goal?

Comment: I want to exclude those applications which are already installed in mobile at the time of buy. But camera, setting is need to display because those applications having icon on UI. Other need to exclude like bluetooth, App Vault, Battery

Comment: ok, so firstly you should form it in words - how would you know if this app should be excluded from your list or not. After you do that, you could just convert your words to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
private void getApps() {
    List<ApplicationInfo> totallist = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
    List<ApplicationInfo> installedlist = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ApplicationInfo> defaultlist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < totallist.size(); i++) {
        if ((totallist.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
            installedlist.add(totallist.get(i));
        }

        if ((totallist.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) {
            defaultlist.add(totallist.get(i));
        }
    }
    Log.d("totallist apps", String.valueOf(totallist.size()));
    Log.d("installedlist apps", String.valueOf(installedlist.size()));
    Log.d("defaultlist apps", String.valueOf(defaultlist.size()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to exclude built in applications

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 type of Non - system applications :

Apps from downloaded from Google Play Store
Apps preloaded in device by manufacturer
Below code will return list of all above applications :

```
ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> mAllApp = 
        mPackageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for(int i = 0; i < mAllApp.size(); i++) {
    if((mAllApp.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
         // 1. Applications downloaded from Google Play Store
        mAllApp1.add(mAllApp.get(i));
    }

    if((mAllApp.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) {
        // 2. Applications preloaded in device by manufecturer
        mAllApp1.add(mAllApp.get(i));
    }
}
```